# Material icon side by side added grammatically via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design

I would like to programmatically modify the content of a `div` tag. I want to add two material icon side by side.

I create the following fiddle, which is a minimal version of what I have to test things:
https://jsfiddle.net/zog20r7n/3/

If I try to modify `line 36` which is

```
<i class=\"material-icons \" >account inbox</i>
```

to the following

```
<i class=\"material-icons md-mine\" >account inbox</i>
```

The first icon is flushed to the right of the second icon.

You can also see that on the first click of the button the icons are flushed to the right of the page and the second icon is centered on a new line.

I don't really understand the behavior, and I don't know if my approach is wrong.
Does Someone has an idea of what is going on here and how to fix it?

I have tried to tweak the CSS because I thought it was the cause of my problem but

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Where do I fail to provide what is asked for? My first sentence explain the desired behavior (icons side by side, and centered), the following paragraph is the minimal example and after I explain the bug on the two example provided.

Comment: Can one reproduce the problem you are having using only the HTML you have provided above in the question?

Comment: I thought so. Is it not the case? I can't tell if this is a rhetorical question.

Comment: A jsfiddle is not an acceptable source for markup or code. You can use it to compliment your example but the **complete** but minimal markup and code that reproduces the problem **must** be contained within the question. Links to third party sources do not count. Your `<i>` example is far from complete.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. I wasn't aware of this. I assume that's why I got multiple downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the correct position expect, but....

Here the original CSS icon.

```
.material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    word-wrap: normal;
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
}
```

Here a format to you override this properties:

```
.material-icons {
  white-space: disble; 
}
```

And elimine spaces between ellements:

```
width: fit-content
```

Comment: with `width: fit-content;` the result is now consistent and appear in the correct order. However it is still flushed to the right for some reason. Do you know why there was a lot of white space? here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zog20r7n/5/

Comment: width: fit-content +  white-space: normal on same rule make this

Answer (score 1):

1. When you use material icons as icon font, you're supposed to use *snake_case* inside the `<i>` tag: (`account box => <i class="material-icons">account_box</i>`).
2. You are using material icons wrong.
   Wrong as in *"invalid"*. There is no icon `account inbox`. Only `account box`, `account balance`, `account balance wallet` and `account circle`.
   That is, IMHO the biggest problem with your code (the messy and hard to get part).
3. You really don't want to apply `text-align: center` to every single element of your page. Adding it to `body` is enough and can be easily overridden.
4. I don't really understand why you completely replace two tags with another version of them (with a `style` attribute, containing a `font-size` declaration) when you could simply toggle a class on the parent and apply the `font-size` based on that, from CSS.

All put together, and a few more details (how I'd do it):

```js
$("#testButton").on('click', function() { $('#divContent').toggleClass('largeFonts')});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v31/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  display: block;
  color:deepskyblue;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 96px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transform: scale(.25);
  transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1)
}
#divContent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
#divContent.largeFonts .material-icons {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="testButton" type="button">Click to test</button>

<div id="divContent">
    <i class="material-icons">account_box</i>
    <i class="material-icons">computer</i>
</div>
```

Note I chose to keep the `font-size` intact (`96px`) in both cases and change the size of the icons using `transform`. Smoother transition (added as demo), a lot lighter on the browser (even if you animate a lot of items at the same time) and, very importantly, it keeps the same `line-height` in all states, which means items on the same line or after them in DOM will not jump up and down based on the change, when you click that button.

Don't forget to [*autoprefix*](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. It made me understand that I had multiple mistakes.